# Using QGIS 3 Plugin Builder on a Mac

Tags: qgis-plugins, mac, qgis-3

Now that I have QGIS 3 running nicely on my Mac. I am having another go at building some plugins.  I have installed the plugin builder plugin and run it without problems and it has generated a source directory.

I cd into the generated source directory and type `make`.  First time it failed to find PyQt5, so I install that with `pip3 install pyqt5-macos-built` and try again.  This time I get:

```
macMini:gpsconnect rful011$ make
pyrcc5 -o resources.py  resources.qrc
/usr/local/bin/python3.6: No module named PyQt5.pyrcc_main
make: *** [resources.py] Error 1
```

The resource file contains:

```
macMini:gpsconnect rful011$ cat resources.qrc 
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/plugins/gps_connect" >
        <file>icon.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Is this what one would expect?  I can't figure out if the plugin builder is not working properly or wether the problem in in my PyQT install.

Comment: It may be useful to try `python3 -m pip install PyQt5` to install PyQt5.